# Java JPA with DiscriminatorColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, discriminator

I have a problem with **DiscriminatorColumn** and **DiscriminatorValue**.

My expectation is :
-TypeOne, TypeTwo, TypeThree are options related to the User.
-A user can have TypeOne only 1 row.
-A user can have TypeTwo or TypeThree multiple rows.
-I used Pageable for search criteria and sorting by **typeOneEntity.optionCode**

**User table.**
|id|user_id|
|-|-|
|1114|a@a.com|

**UserOption table.**
|id|user_id|option_code|option_type_name|
|-|-|-|-|
|1|1114|CODE_1|TYPE_1|
|2|1114|CODE_2|TYPE_2|
|3|1114|CODE_3|TYPE_2|
|4|1114|CODE_4|TYPE_3|

Ps. User.id = UserOption.user_id

I have to create three entities map to this data.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{
    @Column()
    private Long id;

    @Column()
    private String userId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private TypeOne typeOneEntity;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<TypeTwo> typeTwoEntities;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<TypeThree> typeThreeEntities;
}
```

```
@Table(name = "user_option")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "option_type_name")
public abstract class UserOption{

    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column
    private String optionCode;
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "TYPE_1")
public class TypeOne extends UserOption {
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "TYPE_2")
public class TypeTwo extends UserOption {
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "TYPE_3")
public class TypeThree extends UserOption {
}
```

After I build and try to find data, I found two issues.
1.On **typeOneEntity(@OneToOne)** is null.
2.On **@OneToMany** : I got this error ORA-01722: invalid number (error message from Hibernate)

This Entity model that I create it correct or not?
Or it need to change entity model.

Comment: You might need to use a separate join column for each of the subclasses instead. 'Invalid number' doesn't seem related, though, you might have another issue with your setup

Comment: Please share stack traces and the generated SQL.